# For Loop not counting properly

Tags: python, function, for-loop

The prompt for the exercise is as follows:

*Uses a for loop to sum count values from start by increment.
Use: total = sum_count(start, increment, count)
Parameters:
start - the range start value (int)
increment - the range increment (int)
count - the number of values in the range (int)*

What i've come up with:

```
def sum_count(start, increment, count):
    total = start
    for i in range(start, count):
        i += increment
        total += i
    else:
        return total
```

When i call and print the function using values 2, 2, 5, the return should be 30, however I am only returning a value of 17. Which part of my code is wrong?

Comment: Your code as written isn't valid Python. You have an else with no if.

Comment: Also, as a rule people on StackOverflow look down very strongly on asking for solutions to homework problems. Struggling with a homework problem is the thing that helps you learn!

Comment: @NickBailey - `else` is a valid clause in a `for` loop. The example code is valid python.

Comment: Well I'll be darned you're right! I've been writing Python for a decade and I'd never seen that in the wild. Today I learned something

Comment: You keep changing your code in your question, you need to come up with a [mcve] that demonstrates the exact state of your code

Comment: Why should `sum_count(1, 1, 5)` return 15? Shouldn't it be 5 or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @Sayse my bad, ive just been working through and updating as i make progress, I will update it one last time as i have hit another roadblock

Comment: @Jasmijn the program is supposed to add all the values in the range, so in the case of sum_count(1, 1, 5), it would add 1+2+3+4+5=15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to repeat something `x` times, you can use a loop `for _ in range(x)` that doesn't do anything with the value `_` itself.

Reading the task as

> Use a for loop to sum `count` values from `start` by `increment`

means that `count` is not the upper boundary of the range - that's what you did - but the number of values to add up. So for `count` times, increase the `start` value by `increment` and take the sum of the values.

```py
def sum_count(start, increment, count):
    total = 0
    
    for _ in range(count):
        total += start
        start += increment
   
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need a loop for that. It can be done in `O(1)` Time complexity with help of Math.

```
# Arithmetic Progression
def sum_count(start, increment, count):
    total = 2 * start + (count -1) * increment
    total = (n * total) // 2
    return total
```

Comment: The op's task states it needs a for loop

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_count(start, increment, count):
    total = 0
    for i in range(start, count):
        i = start + increment
        total += i
    else:
        return total
```

`start` and `increment` never change during the loop.  They are always 1.

So you're adding `(1 + 1)` four times, for a total of eight.

I don't understand why you expected 15.

Answer (score 0):

First you should note that the loop iterates 4 times not 5 times as you pass count as 5. Now if you want to have a loop to get 15 with 1,1,5 as parameters you can modify your code as:

```
def sum_count(start, increment, count):
    total = 1
    for i in range(start, count):

        i = start + increment
        total = total + i
        start = start + increment

    print("Total: ", total)
    return total
```

And if the total=0 then you get 14 instead of 15.